# Ionic Android Device Testing Failed

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I was trying to run an ionic project on Android device in MAC OS I received the following error

---

> cordova platform add android --save
>   [ERROR] Exception: Command not found: cordova { name: 'Exception', exitCode: 
>           127, fatal: true } Error

```
         at new BaseError 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/errors.js:15:23)
         at new BaseException 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/errors.js:6:9)
         at new FatalException 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/errors.js:13:9)
         at Shell.<anonymous> 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/shell.js:57:31)
         at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
         at rejected 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:105:69)
         at <anonymous>
         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

---

Has anyone encountered this error?

Comment: Have you tried to install the Cordova package `npm install -g cordova`

Comment: Thanks solved after installing Cordova .. it doesn't get automatically installed

Comment: I've provided my comment as the Answer below. Please accept this as it solves your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install *Cordova* package manually, sometimes it doesn't get automatically installed

```
npm install -g cordova
```